# Kill an operation on Kubernete?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am stuck in a situation where my automated jobs stuck in an infinite loop for a **docker container**.
Now I want to stop that operation by some command(s) using **kubectl**

Note: I don't want to restart the container but to stop the current running job (operation).

Comment: You could scale the deployment to 0 with `kubectl scale`. This should stop all jobs. `kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment DEP_NAME -n CORRECT_NAMSPACE`

Comment: Hi you can also use `kubectl delete pod $POD_NAME  --force --grace-period=0`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to immediately remove resources from API you can use these following **flags.**

`kubectl delete pod $POD_NAME --force --grace-period=0`

Keep in mind that when you delete the Resources  forcefully there is a chance of data loses, here is the detail [termination-of-pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods)

you can get further options and information with

`kubectl delete pods --help`